# MySQL search query optimization: Match...Against vs %LIKE%

Tags: mysql, sql

I wanted to build my first real search function. I've been Googling a while, but wasn't able to really make my mind up and understand everything.

My database exists of three InnoDB tables:

- Products: Contains of a product information. Columns: `proID` (primary, auto-increment), `content` (contains up to a few hundred words), `title`, `author`, `year`, and a bunch of others that are not related to the search query. Rows: 100 to 2000.
- Categories: Contains category information: Columns: `catID` (primary, auto-increment), `catName`. Rows: 5-30
- Productscategories: Link between the two above. Each product can be related to multiple categories. Columns: `pcID` (primary, auto-increment), `catID`, `proID`. Rows: 1-5 times amount of products.

My search function offers the following things. They do not have to be filled in. If more than one is filled in, the final query will connect them with the AND-query:

- Terms: Searches the content and title field. Searches on random terms, multiple words can be added, but searches for each of them seperate. Most likely 1 match with the database should be enough for a hit (`OR`-query)
- Year: Searches on the year-column of products.
- Category: Selectable from a list of categories. Multiple possible. The form returns the catID's of the chosen categories.  1 match with the database should be enough for a hit (OR-query)
- Author: Searches on the `author`-column of products

As you may have noticed, when a category is selected, the tables products and productcategories are joined together for the search query. There is also a foreign key set between the two.

To clearify the relations an example of how it should be interpreted(no search for the year!):

Search `WHERE (products.content = term 1 OR products.content = term 2 OR products.title = term 1 OR products.title = term 2 ......) AND (products.author = author) AND (productscategories.catID = catID1 OR productscategories.catID= catID2 ......)`

Also note that I created a pagination system that only shows 10 results on each 'page'.

The question I am stuck with is the following: I wish to optimize this search query, but can't figure out which way is the best.

Most cases I found Googling used the `LIKE %%` mysqli-query. However some used the `MATCH...AGAINST`. I seem to really like the last one because I read it can *sort on relevance* and because it *seems to make the query a lot easier to create* (1 match against the term values instead of plenty of `LIKE %%` combined with `OR`). It seems I would only use it on the Term-searchfield though. However for `MATCH...AGAINST` I will need a MyIsam table (right?), in which I can't use the foreign key to prevent faults in the database.

`MATCH...AGAINST` example (without year field, category field and not joining products and productscategories):

```
SELECT *,MATCH (content,title) AGAINST ('search terms' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS relevance 
FROM products WHERE (MATCH (content,title) AGAINST ('search terms' IN BOOLEAN MODE)) AND
author='author' SORT BY relevance LIMIT 10
```

`%LIKE%` example(without year field, category field and not joining products and productscategories) and sadly no relevance sorting:

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE
(content LIKE '%term1%' OR content LIKE '%term2' OR title LIKE '%term1%' OR title LIKE '%term2%')
AND (author='author') SORT BY title LIMIT 10
```

I could make a relevance sorting by using the `CASE` and add 'points' if a term comes in the title or the content? Or would that make the query too heavy for performance?

So what is the best way to make this kind of query? Go with Innodb and `LIKE`, or switch to MyIsam and use the `MATCH...AGAINST` for sorting?

Comment: What does 'explain' say when you run it on your query?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You dont have to switch to MyIsam. Fulltext indexing is supported in Mysql 5.6 and higher.

I usually recommend using fulltext indexes. Create a fulltext index on your columns title,author,year

Then you can run a fulltext query on all 3 at the same time, and apply IN BOOLEAN MODE to really narrow your searches. This is ofcourse something you have to decide for yourself but the options in fulltext are more.

However, if you are running queries that spawn between a range, date for instance or a simple string. Then a standard index is better but for tekst searching in different columns, fulltext index is the way to go!

Read this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-search.html

Comment: What version are you using now?

Comment: You could install a server instance and dump your data using mysqldump and then import them into the new instance. Then try it to see how it works.

Comment: No idea what the last thing is you posted. At this moment I'm just on localhost with xampp version 3.2.1

Comment: Ok that is using mysql 5.5, Fulltext is only supported with myisam. Then you have to switch to mysiam to use fulltext or upgrade mysql.

Comment: I will be trying to install the newest version to my xampp, yet I do not know or the future site will support it

Comment: MATCH...AGAINST works only for MyISAM tables, not for InnoDb tables ?